# How do I turn the values from an object into an array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function that is polling for temperature data:

```
{"a":"43",
"b":"43",
"c":"42",
"d":"43",
"e":"40",
"f":"41",
"g":"100",
"h":"42.6"}
```

I want to be able to graph that data over time, but I can't figure out the best way to map the above data, to something like the below data:

```
temps: [{
    name: "a",
    data: ["43","42","43"]
  },
    name: "b",
    data: ["43","42","43"]
  },
    etc...
  ]
```

I have tried the code below, and tried to figure out the javascript map function, but I keep running into scoping problems where "this" isn't the same thing as it was in the parent:

```
this.temp_names.forEach(function(e){
    if(typeof this.temps[e] == "undefined") {
      this.temps[e] = []
    }
    this.temps.e.unshift(this.sys_telemetry.S.temps)
    if (this.temps.e.length > 10) {
      this.temps.e.pop()
    }
})
```

where "temp_names" was an array of the keys.

I'm doing this in VueJS, so the "this" is accessing the data in my component.

Comment: [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)?

Comment: try `this.temp_names.forEach((e)=>{` to access `this` properly

Comment: `this.temps.e` is incorrect.  `e` is a variable, not a literal name.  You need to stick with your array syntax.

Comment: The second argument of *forEach* is the object to use as *this*, so `this.temp_names.forEach(function(){...}, this)`, or use an arrow function. Or you can use the third argument of the callback, which is the object being iterated: `this.temp_names-forEach(function(e, i, arr) {...})`.

Comment: May you will need to use [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to solve the problem with the scope.

Comment: How did you get your expected output data? Why do both `a` and `b` have the same elements in their arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), [Object#entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you could do something like this.

```js
const data={"a":"43","b":"43","c":"42","d":"43","e":"40","f":"41","g":"100","h":"42.6"}

const res = Object.entries(data)
.map(([name, data])=>({name, data:[data]}));

console.log(res);
```

Alternative using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map),

```js
const data={"a":"43","b":"43","c":"42","d":"43","e":"40","f":"41","g":"100","h":"42.6"}

const res = Array.from(Object
.entries(data)
.reduce((a,[k,v])=>{
  if(!a.has(k)) a.set(k, []);
  a.get(k).push(v);
  return a;
}, new Map()))
.map(([name, data])=>({name, data}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: The `data` object cannot have duplicate keys, so is the `reduce` necessary here?

Comment: @DecadeMoon you're right, I saw that for each key there were multiple output values so I assumed it was best. But here is an alternative. Much simpler. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`graph that data over time`

Because you want to do this over time, it would make sense to create an array and then using `Object.entries`, & `Array.find`, update the results.

Here is an example.

```js
const values1 = 
  {"a":"43", "b":"43", "c":"42", "d":"43", "e":"40", "f":"41",
  "g":"100", "h":"42.6"};
  
const values2 = 
  {"c":"44", "e":"39"};
  

const results =  [];

function addData(data) {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    let find = results.find(f => f.name === k);
    if (!find) {
      find = {
        name: k,
        data: []
      }
      results.push(find);
    }
    find.data.push(v);
  });
}

addData(values1); //data packet one arrives
addData(values2); //data packet two arrives
  
console.log(results); //results contains both data packet one & two.
```

Comment: Yes, this, thank you! I marked another persons as the correct answer last night...and it worked but didn't append the data, so I figured I would figure it out from there...but you did it for me, so thank you!!! I really appreciate it, python/bash are my go-to language and I haven't used javascript much in the last 3-4 years.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with a simpler data structure like, eg. `{ a: [43, 42, 43], b: [1, 2, 3] }`

ie. instead of having separate `name` and `data` keys, you could use `name` as the key, and the `data` array as the value.

If this would work to represent the timeline for each key, and your initial data is structured like, eg. `[{ a: 43, b: 1, c: 3 }, { a: 42, b: 2, c: 3 }]`, then something like this might be suitable to transform the latter into the former:

```
const output = {};

temp_data.forEach(x => {
  for (const key in x) {
    const y = x[key];

    if (typeof output[key] === 'undefined') {
      output[key] = [];
    }

    output[key].push(y);
  }
});
```

This produces an object whose keys match the keys in your data points (eg. "a", "b", "c", etc), and whose values are an array of all the values for each of these keys, which might be suitable for plotting a timeline.

(Incidentally, if you want to plot these as values on a graph, it might be better to treat the values as numbers - eg. `1, 2, 3` - rather than strings - eg. `"1", "2", "3"`).

There are probably more elegant, functional-style ways of doing this, but this might do the job!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to be able to add multiple datasets to the data object. One approach is to have a data object with methods that know how to do things like add data to themselves, maybe something like the following. You might want to keep the *index* property private, and maybe sort it so it's always in a particular order regardless of the order the values are added.

```js
var data0 = {"a":"43",
"b":"43",
"c":"42",
"d":"43"};

var data1 = {"a":"53",
"b":"53",
"c":"52",
"d":"53",
"e":"65"
};

class DataObject {

  constructor (data) {
    this.index = [];
    this.data = [];
    if (data) {
      this.addData(data);
    }
  }

  addData (data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      let idx = this.index.indexOf(key);
      if (idx == -1) {
        idx = this.index.push(key) - 1;
        this.data.push({name:key, data:[]});
      }
      this.data[idx].data.push(data[key]);
    });
  }
}

// Initialise object with some data
let myData = new DataObject(data0);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myData.data));

// Add more data
myData.addData(data1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myData.data));
```